# This program checks whether two arrays have the same elements in some order

Tags: java

This is the code for the program but it is giving me an error at this part

```java
system.out.println("These are "+sameElements(result1));
```

stating that the method `sameElements(int[], int[])` in the type `Chapter6notes` is not applicable for the arguments `boolean`.

Please help!

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This program checks whether two arrays have the same elements in some order, with the same multiplicities.
 * For example, 1 2 3 and 1 2 3  would be considered identical, but 1 2 3 and 1 2 4 would not be considered identical.
 * @author nikwr
 *
 */
public class Chapter6notes {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        {
        int a[] = new int[30];
        int currentSize = 0;
        while (in.hasNextInt() && currentSize < a.length)
        {
            a[currentSize] = in.nextInt();
            currentSize++;
        }
        {
        int b[]  = new int[30];
        int currentSizes = 0;
        while (in.hasNextInt() && currentSizes < b.length )
        {
            b[currentSizes] = in.nextInt();
            currentSizes++;
        }
        boolean result1;
        System.out.println("These are "+sameElements(result1));
        }
        }   
    public static boolean sameElements(int []a, int []b)
        {
        int sum = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        for(int num : a)
        {   
            sum1 = sum+num; 
        }
        for (int num: b)
        {
            sum2 = sum+num;
        }
        int result = sum1-sum2;
        boolean result1;
            if (result!=0)
            result1 = false;
            else;
            result1 = true;
            return result1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it seems you are confusing _input_ (parameters, or arguments) of a function with the _output_ (the result value of the function when it returns. Look at the function signature : `boolean sameElements(int []a, int []b)`. It needs the two int arrays parameters to do its work. The result of the function is a boolean. Inside the parenthesis, you must give the two arrays to compare. `sameElements(a, b)` would be the correct call if I understand correctly.

Comment: Also, be careful with the if/else in `sameElements`. There's an extra ';' in there that will make it not work as you expect.

Comment: This call doesn't work: `sameElements(result1)` you're invoking the method with a `boolean` even though you should be passing two arrays

Comment: Also, your `sameElements()` method is *extremely* flawed. If I had two int arrays ({5, 2} and {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}), it would return `true`.

Comment: I was able to edit the program to make it more usable and thanks for the correction on the callout! There is still one more issue, when the difference of the two arrays is negative the system mistakes it as true. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: btw @spectric I know it is to an extent but I edited the program to only allow for four numbers to be added so minimize errors. Kind of trying to figure out another way to circumvent this issue.

Comment: First off, you need to check whether the lengths of the two arrays are the same. If they are, loop through one array and use an `if` statement to compare the current itemsin each array. If they are not the same, `return false`. Add a `return true` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        ...

        // sameElements method requires 2 inputs: int[]-array 'a' and int[]-array 'b'
        // OLD: System.out.println("These are " + sameElements(result1));
        // NEW: May not necessarily be correct but it compiles.
        System.out.println("These are " + sameElements(a, b));
    }

    /**
     * Comparing for equality by sum is going to give bad results
     * i.e sum1 = 10 - elements [1, 5, 4]  Is not equal to
     *     sum2 = 10 - elements [0, 6, 4]
     */
    public static boolean sameElements(int[] a, int[] b) {
        int sum = 0;
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        for (int num : a) {
            // this will cumulatively total int[]-array 'a' into 'sum1'. 'sum' is never updated.
            sum1 = sum + num;
            // shorthand for this is sum2 += num
        }
        for (int num : b) {
            // this will cumulatively total int[]-array 'b' into 'sum2'. 'sum' is never updated.
            sum2 = sum + num;
            // shorthand for this is sum2 += num
        }
        int result = sum1 - sum2; // 'sum' never used.
        return result == 0;
    }
```